# Proving $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d) > 1-a-b-c-d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove the following inequality for $a,b,c,d \in (0,1)$:
>   $$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d) > 1-a-b-c-d$$

I have a problem. I don't know if my idea is good

$a=b=c=d $

$(1-a)^4 > 1- 4a $

So, this is true..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$(1-a)(1-b) = 1-a-b+ab > 1-a-b.$$
Likewise,
$$(1-c)(1-d)  > 1-c-d.$$
Therefore,
$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d) > [1-(a+b)][1-(c+d)]>\cdots$$